# How can you run `plink` to copy files?

Tags: putty, plink, pscp

A command line putty's version `plink`. Copying files from Windows system to Linux system is possible using `plink`, but how?

I know the same can be achieved through `pscp`, but I want to achieve this using `plink` because of some reason.

How can you copy files using `plink` command?

Comment: plink is used to send a command to a ssh, and  copy or data transfer ssh uses sftp(shell file transfer protocol) to use that feature you use pscp.

Comment: plink can also be used to transfer standard input of Windows system to standard output of Linux system to copy file contents.

Comment: Can you explain us your reason? It's difficult to suggest a solution, when we do not know your constraints.

Comment: I am only allow to use `Plink` command to do these operations. Installing any other softwares/exe's are not allowed on the system I am working on.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1289455/create-text-file-on-remote-machine-using-plink-putty-with-contents-of-windows-lo

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](https://superuser.com/a/1289488/916720) one way to do it:

```
plink user@host -P 2222 -pw password < test.jpg "cat > ~/test.jpg"
```