# create text file on remote machine using plink/putty with contents of windows local machine's text file

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I want to basically transfer a small text file ~10kb from a windows local machine to a linux machine through putty/plink. I cant use any file transfer tools like pscp/winscp etc So I'm think of getting my text file content to clipboard on window like this :

in cmd.exe in folder location where plink is present -

> type text.txt > ***redirect this output to plink to create text file***

I now want to redirect this clipboard text to plink session so that it could create a text file on the remote linux machine. how to I achieve this? Is this possible?

Comment: so you can use putty to connect to the remote linux machine but cant use pscp/winscp? how come? I just didn't get what you want to do. If you could explain a bit more.

Comment: Scp protocol isnt allowed for us as a policy for file transfers...the alternative they use is a slow and not preferred one for me as my file size is very slow and it get for upload in a queque system

Comment: This works - type localFile.txt | plink.exe user@remoteserver "cat > path/temoteFile.txt" . My question now is how can I send a zip file this way?

Comment: I tried deleting it before I accepted it as the answer. But nevermind it stays now

Comment: If you have SSH you should have [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) available (it uses the SSH protocol). On Windows I use the Bitvise SSH Client that gives SSH terminal sessions and a remote file manager based on SFTP (through which you can transfer files). Filezilla also supports SFTP.

Comment: Hi I cannot use any external file transfer clients

Comment: Define "cannot use"? Forbidden by some authority? Locked up PC on which you cannot add any executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a pipeline, just use redirection:

```
 plink user@host <localfile "cat >hostfile"
```

This won't work (and neither will piping) if `plink` needs to prompt for a password; that means you must either:

- have pageant running with a suitable client key loaded
- use `-i` to specify an unencrypted client key (and an unencrypted key is usually a bad idea)
- use `-pw` to specify the host password (unless the host prohibits password logons for this user)

Answer (score 1):

It on remote mashine is bash you can simply run:

```
cat > remotefile.txt
```

cat will read input of terminal so you can paste your text and press [ctrl]+[d] to end input. cat will write all text to remotefile.txt

You can verify by:

```
cat remotefile.txt
```

this time cat will print remotefile.txt to console.

Or you can use vi or any other editor.

Comment: This works as follows! this way - type localFile.txt  | plink.exe user@remoteserver "cat > path/temoteFile.txt"